# How to adjust the node vertically in Highchart (Organization Chart)?

Tags: reactjs, react-highcharts

We have adjusted the height and width of node at level1 to 30px each, then the node got shifted towards bottom. How we can align the node in the center with the specified height and width ?

`Here is the Demo Example:` https://jsfiddle.net/9drpuz4L/

**With Height & Width (=30px):**
[with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIv4n.png)

**Without Height & Width Adjustment:**
[without](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5Oju.png)

we have tried adding vertical offset, verticalAlign: 'middle' etc., but still it is not working